# Best practice to develop widget using asp.net on the Server side

Tags: asp.net, widget

Hi
I have a hosted web application written in asp.net and would like to publish widgets for use in remote websites. For that purpose I believe I want to use embedded widgets over IFrame.
I therefore need some client side code to retrieve the widget's HTML from the server.
I'd appreciate assistance in the Client\ Server communication. If you have sample code to call a .NET webservice (or any other way) so that I can start by embedding this code within the widget's client UI.
I would also appreciate recommendations for the client UI library (JQuery, ...)

**Thanks a lot !**

Answer (score 1):

Some people find JQuery the best choice for this, but if you would rather not have (or don't need) the overhead of all of the JQuery scripts, you can use a ServiceReference in a ScriptManager to call a .Net WebService.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx) example for that.  There are also examples of loading the HTML from a UserControl via Javascript too if that route would be more fitting for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is i want to embed the code in public websites, which are not mine. I need to provide my clients a simple code (html +js) and I can't rely on them having .NET. I need if possible a way to create a userControl for example and then have it somehow generate html+js code upon request from external website. I dont know if that can even be done. I'll appreciate your responses.

Thanks!